# A workflow is not triggering a second workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

The workflow in file `inrisk.packages.ci.yml` generates a `tag` and a `realise` of the code when a push is done in the `develop` branch. The below works as expected.

```
name: Code Int

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'infra/**'

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Checks-out to $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Basic Checks
        run: |
          whoami
          ls -lah
          pwd
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      # Create a new release when on develop which triggers the deployment
      - name: Bump version and push tag
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop'
        uses: mathieudutour/github-tag-action@v4.5
        id: tag_version
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Create Release
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop'
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ steps.tag_version.outputs.new_tag }}
          release_name: Release ${{ steps.tag_version.outputs.new_tag }}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
```

The below workflow in file `inrisk.packages.cd.yml` and is suppose to be triggered when ever a `tag`/`realise` is `created`/`published`.

```
name: Code Deploy

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'
  release:
    types:
      - published
      - created
      - released

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Checks-out to $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      - name: Install Yarn
        run: npm install -g yarn
      - uses: chrislennon/action-aws-cli@v1.1
      - name: Install, Build and Deploy
        run: |
          whoami
          ls -lah
          pwd
```

The second workflow `Code Deploy` dose not get trigger after `Code Int` `publishes`/`created` a `tag`/`realise`

However when I manually create a `realise`/`tag` the second workflow `Code Deploy` get triggered

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be by design as stated [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#triggering-new-workflows-using-a-personal-access-token) .This is to stop recursive workflow runs.

I used this [article](https://stevenmortimer.com/running-github-actions-sequentially/) to get around the problem