# Can you move a folder as part of a github action triggered by a push and ignore the 2nd trigger?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to use GitHub actions to move and commit a file into a subfolder whenever a file is pushed into the Github repo.

This is because I have a 3rd party tool that only pushes files into the root of the project and I need the files to go to a subdirectory to have it integrate/work with other 3rd party tools.  (I know it's kind of silly)

How do I do this without having Github actions get triggered again and go into a loop?  I suppose maybe there is a way to check conditionally that there are no files left to move, but this would still make it potentially gets triggered twice with nothing happening on the 2nd loop.  Is there a clean, elegant way to only have it run once and ignore the 2nd push that happens as part of the action?

Comment: Did you check on.paths? It might help achieve what you want: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths

Comment: By default, a workflow doesn't trigger another workflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63966764/a-workflow-is-not-triggering-a-second-workflow

Comment: oh nice - yeah both comments - about using paths and not having it default to recursive seems to solve it